# Entity Integrity

Tags: sql, database, entity, integrity

I would like to understand this concept better, as I am very new to database creation. I was hoping someone could provide me with a good SQL example of entity integrity, one which a beginner could learn from and understand easily. I figured that the community here could provide me with some well written examples that I could benefit from for my upcoming database management courses.

Comment: Do you mean Referential Integrity?  Have you even tried to Google first?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is old and you probably have an answer by now, but maybe this will help someone else.

For a table to exhibit Entity Integrity no part of the Primary Key(PK) may be null and all Primary Key entries must be unique.

For example: No EMP_NUM may be null and all EMP_NUMs must be unique. All employees are uniquely identified by their employee number.

Just as Entity Integrity relates to PKs, Referential Integrity relates to Foreign Keys. For a table to exhibit Referential Integrity, a Foreign Key may have either a null entry (as long as it is not part of the tables PK) or must reference an entry that matches the Primary Key value of the specified table. In  short, every non-null foreign key must reference an existing PK value.

For example: A customer may not yet have an assigned sales rep so you could have a null entry that would still exhibit Referential Integrity, because no invalid entry has occurred. On the other hand, if a customer has been assigned a sales rep (and the FK references a valid sales rep id) you also have Referential Integrity.

Comment: *"For a table to exhibit Entity Integrity no part of the Primary Key(PK) may be null and all Primary Key entries must be unique."* I'm sure you meant to say "no part of any candidate key may be null, and all candidate key entries must be unique".

Comment: Thanks, guys. I have actually completed a majority of my DBM courses now, and I am currently finishing my last advanced one. I appreciate the response though. Hopefully someone who is Googling the topic will find this useful in the future.